# D3 pie chart zero data point changes arc fill color

Tags: d3.js

I am new to the forum and to d3, any help would be appreciated. In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashleighswayn/zztt3gvL/4/) would like to:

1. Link the data "itemLabel" to a specific arc colour. I have 12 "itemLabel's" and 12 colours and want them to stay the same. The problem is when the data `itemValue=0` on any "itemlabel" the colours of all the following arcs then change. I know why it changes (it skips the zero data point and displays the next colour on a non-zero data point), I just don't know how to fix it. I have read code all day and still no luck. For example "Australian shares" should always be the dark green `#8BC92F` as the slider is moved.
2. Start the slider in the middle. I know how to position the slider in the middle however I would like to have the graph rendered for the position on loading.

Thank you

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range([ "#06a6d8", "#5CBEE6","#94CFE6", "#8BC92F", "#C1DA12", "#F2F001", "#FEB132", "#FB9400", "#EB6D00", "#F9588A", "#F22766", "#CE8AFF"]);

.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You use an index for filling the segments:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
```

So, when during the update the length of your data is changed (`itemValue=0` case) the filling colour for the appropriate arc also changes.

You should set the domain for your `color` scale:

```
const dataLabels = dataStructure[0].data
  .map(function(item) { return item.itemLabel; });
```

Save the array of labels to `dataLabels` variable

```
color.domain(dataLabels);
```

Pass it to `.domain` property. After that, you can get the associated colour by the label name:

```
paths.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.name); }) // <--!!!
  .transition()
    .duration(tweenDuration)
    .attrTween("d", pieTween);

paths
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.name); }) // <--!!!
  .transition()
    .duration(tweenDuration)
    .attrTween("d", pieTween);
```

2) You should pass the index of the dataset that you want to show after the page loading to `update` function and to `value` property of the slider configuration object. You have the length of data equal to 21, so you should pass 10 or 11 for showing the slider position at the middle.

```
var middleDatasetIndex = Math.floor(dataStructure.length / 2); // = 11

$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value: middleDatasetIndex, // <-- !!!
    min: 0,
    max: 21,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        update(ui.value);
        console.log(ui.value);
      }
})
...
update(middleDatasetIndex); // <--!!!
```

Check [the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ocLjf4wu/1/).